# Are there medical imaging devices to look inside artery?

Tags: biomedical-engineering, biomedical-technology

Are there medical imaging devices to look inside artery? If yes, what is there sensitivity i.e. smallest object they can detect?

Comment: Smallest object really depends on the size of the vessel and type of object. i.e., it is much easier to detect a small object that occludes a vessel than one that does not; it is much easier to detect a small, dense object with IVUS than one that is similar in density to the artery wall; it can be easier to detect an object on the inner lumen of a vessel rather than deep in the adventitia, etc.